# placeholder loaction in mat-input

Tags: angular, angular-material2, placeholder, mat-input

I'm using angular6 with angular material to create this neat website.

I'm using a `mat-form-field` with `mat-input` so show a text input element with a `placeholder` text.

the placeholder text position has two states.

one! when the text input is empty and you are not focused into that element:

[image: empty mat-input]

and the other when you focused on the input text and/or you the input text is not empty

[image: mat-input with text]

I want the mat-input element to be in the 2nd state. to show the placeholder above the text input element even when there is no text in it and i'm not focused on that element.

I know i can make a work-around and add some sort of empty space to the value of the element.. but is there a more elegant way to achieve what I need?

thanks!!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `floatLabel="always"`, which is the input property binding for `mat-form-field`

```
<mat-form-field style="width: 100%" floatLabel="always">
  <input matInput placeholder="Enter Name">
</mat-form-field>
```

Working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/float-vuzbjk)